# history.pushState and window.location.href out of sync

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, browser-history

I am seeing a strange issue on an Android mobile device relating to the History API. I run some code to update the page url using `history.pushState` and then afterwards check the value of `window.location.href`. I would expect the value of `href` to equal the value that I just pushed, but it still has the previous value. When I check the browser url bar the location has been updated correctly. This code reproduces the issue:

```
function go(){
    console.log(window.location.href); // this shows url of '.../page1.html'
    window.history.pushState({}, '', './page2.html');
    console.log(window.location.href); // this still shows url of '.../page1.html'
    // browser address bar shows url of '.../page2.html'
}
```

I have seen the issue on the default Android 2.3.4 browser, when I run the same code in a desktop browser it behaves as I would expect (ie `window.location.href` has the value that I pushed) - can anyone confirm that this is a browser bug, rather than expected behaviour?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=history

See 'known issues' tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See android bug report
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17471